# Android CookieManager

Tags: java, android, cookiemanager

I have an application that makes several web calls in order to get authenticated after which a JSON is returned. My web calls are to an https server and I am using HTTPURlConnection.

I need to store the session in a cookie, after researching around, I found this

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Under the sessions with cookies header, it tells you to use this code here

```
   CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
   CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
```

However when I try using this code, the new CookieManager(); part highlights in red and says

> The constructor CookieManager is not visible

and the Cookiehandler.setDefault also highlights in red and says

> The method setDefault(CookieHandler) in the type CookieHandler is not applicable for the arguments (CookieManager)

Does anyone know why this is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your import to see if you are using the right `CookieManager` class - which should be `java.net.CookieManager`

Comment: Could you post your code please. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html there is definitely a public constructor. Are you using the right CookieManager class?

Comment: Rajesh was right, I changed the import, didn't work, so then tried clicking fix project set up, and worked. Cheers Rajesh

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably trying to use the wrong `CookieManager` class. In Android there are 2 classes...

```
android.webkit.CookieManager
java.net.CookieManager
```

For this context, you need to use the `java.net.CookieManager` class.

Comment: Got it working now, however when I try to run my application it crashes and says no class found error on java.net.CookieManager. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: It sounds like you're missing the connection to your Android library package. Check the android settings and make sure that you're including one of the Android libraries.

Comment: Ahh, after doing some research found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354294/urlconnection-with-cookies

Says that only works on API 9 upwards, so no use to me sadly

Comment: Bugger. As a suggestion, if you're feeling adventurous, you might be able to get the source code for the API9 version of `CookieManager` and add that in to your project as `com.myprogram.CookieManager` (not sure how much work this would involve though, if there's a lot of dependencies).

Comment: The dependencies would worry me with that method, will just have to look for an alternative, bleh!!!