# How to enable cookies when opening a URL's connection

Tags: java, url, cookies, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am trying to use the following code to get the redirected URL and then do some processing on it. But when I print the redirected link, it goes to a page that informs the absence of cookies. how is it possible to enable cookies while opening the url's connection?

```
 String url = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0210059";
 URLConnection con = new URL( url ).openConnection();
 con.getInputStream();
 String redirctedURL= con.getURL().toString();
 System.out.println(redirctedURL);
```

Comment: The problem is how to handle cookies. Please look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354294/urlconnection-with-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

When using java `UrlConnection`'s, you should handle the cookies by yourself, to read and set the cookies, you can use the `setRequestProperty()` and `getHeaderField()` of `URLConnection`.

The remaining part is parsing the cookies by yourself, an example how the can be done is as follows:

```
Map<String, String> cookie = new HashMap<>();
public URLConnection doConnctionWithCookies(URL url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("&");
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : cookie.entrySet()) {
        builder.append(urlenEncode(entry.getKey()))
               .append("=")
               .append(urlenEncode(entry.getValue()))
               .append("&");
    }
    builder.setLength(builder.length() - 1);
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", builder.toString());
    con.connect();
    // Parse cookie headers
    List<String> setCookie = con.getHeaderFields().get("set-cookie");
    // HTTP Spec state header fields MUST be case INsentive, I expet the above to work with all servers 
    if(setCookie == null)
        return con;
    // Parse all the cookies
    for (String str : setCookie) {
        String[] cookieKeyValue = str.split(";")[0].split("=",2);
        if (cookieKeyValue.length != 2) {
            continue;
        }
        cookie.put(urlenDecode(cookieKeyValue[0]), urlenDecode(cookieKeyValue[1]));
    }
    return con;
}

public String urlenEncode(String en) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(en, "UTF-8");
}

public String urlenDecode(String en) {
    return URLDecoder.decode(en, "UTF-8");
}
```

The above implementation is a very stupid and crude way of implementation cookies, while it works, it totally ignores the fact that cookies can also have a host parameter to prevent identification cookies be shared across multiple hosts.

A better way than doing it yourself can be using a library dedicated for the task like Apache HttpClient.